# not able to set focus on TextBox in a GWT app

Tags: gwt, textbox

This should not be causing me so much pain but it is. It is a very weird problem. In a GWT application, I have two .java files, login.java and application.java.
In login.java, I'm creating a user login page where if the username and password is verified the user is logged into the application and application.java takes from here.

Now in application. java's onModuleLoad() this is how i'm starting with a login page.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
  Login login = new Login();
  login.textBoxUsername.setFocus(true);
  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(login);}
```

This works great, except for the tiny problem of not being able to set focus on the username TextBox when the page loads. I have tried evrything I can think of. But the focus just doesn't get set on the TextBox. If anyone can suggest a solution, please do. Your help is greatly appreciated.

**Solution**: (In case it helps anyone facing the same issue)

```
final Login login = new Login();
  Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {
        public void execute () {
            login.textBoxUsername.setFocus(true);
        }
   });

  RootLayoutPanel.get().add(login);
```

Comment: You may need to call `setFocus()` after the login widget has been added to the `RootLayoutPanel` -- have you tried that?

Comment: yes, when i call setFocus() after RootLayoutPanel.get().add(login); the login screen does not load.

Comment: Are you getting any script error if you call setFocus() after RootLayoutPanel.get().add(login); ? I think browser takes some time to load your login widget. Can you please try the setFocus call inside the gwt timer block with 5 seconds of interval? Then we can figure out where is the problem happening  exactly.

Comment: @Din If it takes some time to create a Login widget, or add it to the RootLayoutPanel, the next call won't happen until that's complete. @sherry Are you running in Dev Mode so you can see any GWT errors?

Comment: @Din: You are right,the browser does take time to load the login widget although this delay is not visible to the user. I was not able to figure out when the load of login widget was being completed. Following through with this concept I used @Peter's suggestion below. Using DeferredCommand works! It waits till the login widget is loaded then calls setFocus(). Although DeferredCommand is deprecated and I'll have to find what can be used in its stead. But at least I'm going somewhere now.. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Jason you are right. I think I have found the solution. Thank you for your response.

Comment: @sherry: Good that you have fixed this issue. :-)

Comment: @Jason Hall: This is purely the timing issue. In gwt creating widget is different and loading/rendering widget is different. As I have mentioned in my first comment it takes some time to load(render) not for creation. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using [Scheduler.scheduleDeferred()](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/Scheduler.html#scheduleDeferred%28com.google.gwt.core.client.Scheduler.ScheduledCommand%29):

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    Login login = new Login();
    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand () {
        public void execute () {
            login.textBoxUsername.setFocus(true);
        }
    });
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add(login);       
}
```

**Update:** answer updated to use `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()` instead of [`DeferredCommand`](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsDelayed.html#deferred), which is deprecated.

Comment: Thanks Peter! Your solution worked. Although this is deprecated, so i'll have to find the class that will do this in the current version of GWT. At least you have suggested a place to start, thank you.

Comment: Indeed, you should use `Scheduler.scheduleDeferred()`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred()`?

Comment: Just one question, everything is wrapped up within the `onModuleLoaded` function, right? Similar to jQuery's `document.ready()`. So won't that address the issue off setting the focus only after the widget has been loaded in the first place? Why do we need to take care of that separately through this hack?

Comment: @Cupidvogel - No, `onModuleLoad()` can be called before DOM is ready and `body.onload()` is called: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects?hl=en#DevGuideBootstrap

Comment: Well, since `onModuleLoad` doesn't guarantee that the methods will act on the elements only after they are loaded, do wee need to wrap all event handlers attached to elements, like `keyup`, `click`, etc also in `scheduler`?

Comment: @Cupidvogel: Yes, if you address DOM elements that were defined in page HTML.

Comment: Ummm, I didn't get what you meant. There are two kind of elements, one defined statically in the HTML page, and the 2nd generated within the `onModuleLoaded` function and added to he `DOM`. Do we need to attach event handlers to both these kind of elements within `scheduler`?

Answer (score 1):

Why using `DefferedCommand`, I think it's better to  use `someWidget.getElement().focus()` which is a native Javascript. I'm using it everywhere, I've not seen any problem.

Comment: I have used it in many places too. Well, it did not work in this case. Like its been explained above, it is not possible to know when the login widget load is completed, in order to use `someWidget.getElement().focus()`. so we need to use `DeferedCommand` or `scheduleDeferred` to achieve this. `deferredCommand` is executed after the browser event loop returns.

Answer (score 0):

If your Widget extends Composite, you can:

```
@Override
protected void onAttach() {
    super.onAttach();
    textBoxUsername.setFocus(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be so easy for GWT to store a 'wantsFocus' in the internal state, and call focus after the widget is attached.  We are still waiting after many years for that feature however...

Still, even after the attach handler is called, setFocus does not always work.

So in the meantime, our GwtUtil library has used the following code.  It is a combination of several other solutions, and has been wrapped in a utility function:

```
static public void setFocus(final FocusWidget focusWidget) {
    if (focusWidget.isAttached()) {
        Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
            @Override
            public void execute() {
                focusWidget.setFocus(true);
            }
        });
    } else {
        focusWidget.addAttachHandler(new AttachEvent.Handler() {
            @Override
            public void onAttachOrDetach(AttachEvent event) {
                if (event.isAttached()) {
                    Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute() {
                            focusWidget.setFocus(true);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
setFocus(myTextBox);
```

It makes sense to use a utility function; If and when GWT finally makes setFocus work, you won't have to change your source code in multiple places.