# How to set focus on TextBox in GWT Popup Panel?

Tags: java, gwt, popup, focus, setfocus

I want to set focus on textbox in popup panel. I have Login popup panel which contains textbox for username and password, So How can I set focus on username when popup loads/showed?
I am using GWT/Java.

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you call .show() on your popup panel, use this:

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new ScheduledCommand() {

    @Override
    public void execute() {
        myTextField.setFocus();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean TextBox? There is no TextField in the standard GWT library.

```
textField.setFocus(true);
```

Possible duplicate, this thread might answer your question: [not able to set focus on TextBox in a GWT app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5944612/1257372)

Comment: as the link suggested Scheduler is not working... :(.
I think my login UI is on popup...thats why it is giving problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you init your field you can use

```
textField.setFocus(true);
```

but more preferable this way

```
FocusSetter.setFocus(textFocus, true);
```

because you should not control is field initialize or not

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
textField.requestFocusInWindow();
```